# Read text file C#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, windows-ce, streamreader, textreader

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileLoc = @"c:\wms.txt";

        if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
        {
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(tr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly in when I create a Windows Application.

When I use the same code in a Device application - Windows CE i get error:

[image]

Using: .Net 2.0  , visual Studio 2005

Comment: Can the exception text be any more clear?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry, not sure I understand what you trying to say?

Comment: looks like you have an extra slash at the beginning there.

Comment: Windows CE does not have a concept of [drive letters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899726.aspx). Your path there should simply be `@"\wms.txt"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your device does not have a `c` drive. Replace

```
string fileLoc = @"c:\wms.txt";
```

with

```
string fileLoc = @"wms.txt";
```

It seems that the root folder is automatically added to your path with a `\`

Comment: Wouldn't you want the "\" still left in there, or else you will get a relative location?

Comment: @gunr2171 As far as I remember, Windows CE does not have a concept of "current directory" either, so all paths are automatically assumed to start at root, which means that `\\` is really optional.

Answer (score 3):

Windows CE does not have a concept of [drive letters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899726.aspx). Your path there should simply be `@"\wms.txt"`.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
string fileLoc = @"c:\wms.txt";
```

or

```
string fileLoc = "c:\\wms.txt";
```

Comment: Your first example is exactly what the OP tried, and the second is just another way to escape a backslash.